# UITabBarController shows blank screen

Tags: swift

I am starting an app programmaticaly with no storyboards. When I try to make my UITabBarController the root view controller it looks like [image: this] The background color should be red and the tab item should be a house. What could be the problem?

SceneDelegate code:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
               window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
               window?.windowScene = windowScene
               window?.rootViewController =  TabBarController()
               window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

HomeViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
}
```

TabBarController code:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupTab()
    }
    
    func setupTab(){
        let homeVC = HomeViewController()
        homeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "House"), tag: 0)
        let homeNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
        tabBarController?.viewControllers = [homeNC]
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the tintColor (`self.tabBar.tintColor = yourColor`) and/or the unselected item tintColor (`self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = yourColor`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work for setting up the tab view controller needs to be done while you are setting up the scene in the SceneDelegate.  The HomeViewContoller's viewDidLoad was never being called.

```
 var homeNavigationController : UINavigationController!
    var secondHomeNavigationController : UINavigationController!
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        
        let tabBarController = TabBarController()

        homeNavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
        secondHomeNavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
        tabBarController.viewControllers = [homeNavigationController, secondHomeNavigationController]
 
 //       let item1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "House"), tag: 0)
        let item1 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .featured, tag: 0)
        let item2 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .bookmarks, tag: 1)
        homeNavigationController.tabBarItem = item1
        secondHomeNavigationController.tabBarItem = item2
        
        window?.rootViewController =  tabBarController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupTab()
    }
    
    
    func setupTab(){

    }

}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
}
```